# Error in JDBC connection using logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am trying to get my sqlserver table into **Elasticsearch** using **Logstash**. For that i have created below configuration file.

```
input {
  jdbc { 
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:sqlserver://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:1433/DB_name"
    jdbc_user => "devuser"
    jdbc_password => "devuser"
    jdbc_driver_library => "D:/Mssqljdbc/sqljdbc4-2.0.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    statement => "SELECT * FROM sample"
    }
  }
output {
  stdout { codec => json_lines }
  elasticsearch {
  hosts => "localhost"
  index => "testmigrate"
  document_type => "data"
  }
}
```

then i am using `bin\logstash -f sqltable.conf` to execute it.
But i am getting

> Error: Java::ComMicrosoftSqlserverJdbc::SQLServerException: The port
>   number 1433/DB_name is not valid.

i checked i am able to ping the particular ip address and the port is also openbut still i am getting the same error. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of digging i did a small change and it worked for me. I added **databaseName** in front of the DB_name.

```
input {
  jdbc { 
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:sqlserver://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:1433;databaseName=DB_name"
    jdbc_user => "devuser"
    jdbc_password => "devuser"
    jdbc_driver_library => "D:/Mssqljdbc/sqljdbc4-2.0.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    statement => "SELECT * FROM sample"
    }
  }
output {
  stdout { codec => json_lines }
  elasticsearch {
  hosts => "localhost"
  index => "testmigrate"
  document_type => "data"
  }
}
```

It is quite strange i didn't found this in any of the documentation.